# Using Weave Net Docker Swarm Adapter to allow services to communicate

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a Docker Swarm cluster setup as follows:

Setup on node 1

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr ${NODE_1_IP} --data-path-port=7789
```

Setup on node 2

```
docker swarm join --advertise-addr ${NODE_2_IP} --token XXX ${NODE_1_IP}:2377
```

I have then installed weave on both nodes as follows.

```
sudo curl -L git.io/weave -o /usr/local/bin/weave
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/weave

docker plugin install weaveworks/net-plugin:latest_release
docker plugin disable weaveworks/net-plugin:latest_release

docker plugin set weaveworks/net-plugin:latest_release WEAVE_PASSWORD=XXX
docker plugin enable weaveworks/net-plugin:latest_release
```

I wanted to set a password because I need the network to be encrypted.
I then set up a network and a service. The constraint makes the service consist of one container running on node 2.

```
docker network create --driver=weaveworks/net-plugin:latest_release --attachable testnet_weave_encrypted

docker service create --network=testnet_weave_encrypted --name web_encrypted --publish 80 --replicas=1  --constraint 'node.labels.datastore001 == true' nginx:latest
```

Finally I test it inside another container running on node 1:

```
docker run --rm --name alpine --net=testnet_weave_encrypted -ti alpine:latest sh
apk add --no-cache curl
curl web_encrypted
```

This fails with the message:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to web_encrypted port 80: Host is unreachable
```

I know that web_encrypted is not wrong because when I try a different value I get a different error.

After bashing my head against this wall for hours I have discovered that I can do the following on node 1:

```
curl web_encrypted.1.lsrdyz8n66jdotaqgdzk9u1uo
```

And it works!

But of course this is useless to me because the exact container name will change every time the service recreates it.

Is this a bug in the weave plugin or have I missed a step in setting this up?

Comment: By accident I have discovered that "curl tasks.web_encrypted" works. I can redo all my setup to add "tasks." infront of all my urls but that seems strange. Why doesn't web_encrypted alone work?

Comment: It's not working because of it wrong resolve IP (https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/3382), but with your "workaround" I can solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If you specify endpoint_mode as DNSRR, you should be able to use the service name as well as any aliases you specify. The weavenet network in the snippet below was created using the Weave network plugin.

```
host#docker service create --network name=weavenet,alias=ngx --endpoint-mode=dnsrr --name nginx nginx
host#docker run -it -d --name alpine --network=weavenet alpine:curl
host#docker exec -it alpine sh
/ # curl nginx
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
....
/ # curl ngx
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```